# Kendo UI .NET MVC wrapper API for Mobile

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

I can't find anywhere on the KendoUI site that has API documentation for the mobile wrappers.  I see APIs for the standard ASP.NET MVC wrappers, but not for the mobile wrappers.  Am I missing something?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started I think: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/mobileactionsheet/overview

In the tree on the left, there are nodes for all the different controls.  You can also see some of the view code on their demo site, for example: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/drawer/index.html#/ (scroll down, click on "ASP.NET MVC"

Comment: If this helped you / was what you're looking for, please mark as answer for the community.  Thanks.